# How to show only one li at a time inside ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, click, hide, show, ngfor

I have the below code which displays the icon as part of anchor tag and on click of it , I am showing a list mentioned below with li tag.  The problem here is since the li is associated with a single ngFor , say when i=2, the li gets created twice, when i=3, li gets created thrice. How to show only one li at a time and hide others.?

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index ">
    <div>{{person.name}}</div>
    <a href='#' data-target='dropdown3' class="sharebtn" (click)="shareIconClicked($event, i);"></a>
    <ul id='dropdown3' [ngClass]="{'popupShare': showPopup == true}">
        <li><a>Copy Message</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to add `*ngIf='i==0'` ?

Comment: try changing `id` since multiple elements will have same `id`. try `id="dropdown{{i}}"`

Comment: code looks fine something trivial you might be missing like a closing brace(tough question have proper html).

Comment: Can u help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493257/how-to-show-only-one-ul-at-a-time-in-angular-using-ngfor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ngIf in li tag

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index ">
              <div>           
                   {{person.name}}
              </div>
            <a href='#' data-target='dropdown3' class="sharebtn" (click)="shareIconClicked($event, i);"></a>
              <ul id='dropdown3' [ngClass]="{'popupShare': showPopup == true}" >
                <li *ngIf="i<1"><a >Copy Message</a></li>
              </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad that your problem has fixed

Comment: I have a issue here. The problem is everytime the list always gets displayed on position 0 irrespective of the icon i clicked.It should display in 3rd position  if i clicked 3rd icon