# How to show only one ul at a time in angular using ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the above image which has Add Person button, on click of Add person, Person 1 row gets created and so on. On the right end of each row, I have a share icon, on click of an icon, I wanted to open a ul element. The problem is the number of popups that gets displayed depends on the number of rows. If 5 rows are added, then 5 popups are displayed. Ideally, I need only one popup to be displayed, for Person 4 row it should be the popup with 33( basically the popup the is present for that particular row). I tried to add *ngIf = i> 1 condition, but the popup with 00 is only displayed every time which is not correct because the popup position will always be in parallel to Person 1 position.

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index">
      <div>
        <div class="userIcon">
          <div>
            <img class="person-img" src="assets/images/person.png" alt="My Profile">
          </div>
          <div>
            <input id="form3" class="form-control" type="text">
            <label for="form3" class="">{{person.name}}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input id="form5" class="form-control" #enteramount type="text">

          <a class='dropdown-trigger sharebtn' href='#' data-target='dropdown{{i}}' (click)="shareIconClicked($event, i,  enteramount)"></a>
            {{i}}
          <ul id='dropdown{{i}}'  [ngClass]="{'popupShare': showPopup == true}" class='dropdown-content sharebtn-content'>
            <li>  {{i}}
             Copy Message
            </li>

            <li>Whatsapp</li>

            <li>Email</li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Below image represents the single popup after adding ngIf = 'isFirst'. I have clicked the Person 4 share icon. If I click the Person 3 share or Person 5 share icon, the popup is always positioned on the first row.

Comment: Try to add condition like *ngIf = i == 0 at the parent div of popup html

Comment: Popup code is placed inside the ul element . Paren div of pop up means ?

Comment: <div "this div*******">
        <div>
          <input id="form5" class="form-control" #enteramount type="text">

Comment: Doesnt work . This doesnt display the input field and share icon from second click onwards

Comment: Which version of angular?

Comment: Angular 4 version

Comment: please check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add check for `first` using `*ngFor` like this -

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons; first as isFirst">
....
            <ul id='dropdown{{i}}' *ngIf='first'  [ngClass]="{'popupShare': showPopup == true}" class='dropdown-content sharebtn-content'>
...</ul>
</div>
```

For more in details refer official docs -

- https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: What about let i = index? Should i remove that?

Comment: If not in use you can remove , totally depends on you. Else you can use both by  `;` seprator

Comment: I did two changes ,  <div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index; first as isFirst"> and *ngIf='first'  . The pop up is not showing now

Comment: Just make change like this `<div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index; first as isFirst"> and *ngIf='isFirst'`

Comment: Actually with this it shows a single popup . But I am facing the same issue which i was facing as mentioned in question . The popup is displayed always on first position irrespective of the icon i clicked. I have added a image with Person 4 share icon clicked for better understanding. Please help.

Comment: I think in this case you need to play with `index` of `*ngFor` and for position you need to make changes in css

Comment: That is what i was trying to figure out how and I am not getting solution,

Comment: You got any clues on this? @Pardeep

Comment: @Nancy I have shared the basic concept Now I feel you can itself create logic accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You should try angular Mat-menu feature like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons; first as isFirst">
   .... code

  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Share</button>
   <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="sharteWithFacebook(person)">Facebook</button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="shareWithWhatapp(person)">Whatsapp</button>
   </mat-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: As per above given example create two function sharteWithFacebook & shareWithWhatapp with one person as an argument there you will get the person with share button clicked

Comment: I dont want to use mat menu . I am trying to figure out from my existing code itself.

Comment: So for that you must have unique popup Id for each row's popup and share button should call that id as per clicked row.

Comment: This is what I am doing . Share button popup and share icon has unique ids . As you see in the code , i have binded {{i}} for both <a> tag and <ul> tag , but still doesnt work .

Comment: If share icon for Person 4 is clicked , then only popup number 3 should be displayed because i=3, but all of them are displayed .

Comment: I have the id of the element that has been clicked inside typescript. Is it possible to use the id=dropdown3 and show only that popup and hide other popups

Comment: #enteramount should be #enteramount_{{i}} and in function call too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184303/discussion-between-nancy-and-vijay-sankhat).